# Python Requests to access flask route with url variable

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have been trying to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) to access a flask web service I have created. The problem I am encountering though is how to access routes which have url variables in them.

for example if I have route:

```
@app.route('/v1/game/<gameid>', methods = ['POST'])
def testing(gameid):
  return jsonify({'status':'success'})
```

I have not been able to find a way in order to access this route with requests.
My most recent attempts being

```
def test_testing(self):
  url = self.base + 'gameid'
  payload = {'<gameid>': 200}
  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload) ,headers=headers)
```

and

```
def test_testing(self):
  url = self.base + '<gameid>'
  payload = {'<gameid>': 200}
  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url, params = payload, headers=headers)

def test_testing(self):
  url = self.base + '200'
  payload = {'otherdata': 'stuff'}
  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url, data = payload, headers=headers)
```

Both return 404's so I know they aren't reaching

Comment: Try `print`ing out the URLs you're accessing with Requests and hitting them with curl to see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what my issue was. I was somehow causing python to add '/' character to the number I was trying to add to the url.

For other to reference the correct way to achieve the functionality I was looking for is

```
def test_testing(self):
  url = self.base + str(gameid)  #the base ends with '/v2/game/'
  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url,headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've specified it, the `gameid` goes into the URL, not the payload. For example: `/v1/game/1234`

Comment: I have tried just concatenating the number I need to the url but that also returns a 404 'edited' to demonstrate

Comment: Does `self.base` end in a trailing slash?

Comment: Yes it does. self.base has worked with every request I have made beforehand. The only issues that pop up are when I'm trying to access a route with a variable in it.